# pandas date_range error "ValueError: Of the three parameters: start, end, and periods, exactly two must be specified"

Tags: python, pandas, date-range, valueerror

I have to develop production code to work with pandas 0.22.0. I get `ValueError: Of the three parameters: start, end, and periods, exactly two must be specified` when I run the following code

```
import pandas as pd
pd.date_range(start='2020-03-20 00:00', end='2020-03-21 00:00', periods=5)
```

why is this happening?

Comment: working fine for me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have something to do with the pandas version.
When I checked it with python 3.6.8 (pandas==0.22.0), I also get the same error:

[image]

But it works fine with python 3.7.3 (pandas==0.24.2):

[image]

As per the documentation for pandas 0.22.0:
Of the three parameters: start, end, and periods, exactly two must be specified. 
[See the Notes section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.date_range.html)

Also checked it for the latest version of pandas. This is what it says:
Of the four parameters start, end, periods, and freq, exactly three must be specified. If freq is omitted, the resulting DatetimeIndex will have periods linearly spaced elements between start and end (closed on both sides).
[See the Notes Section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

Answer (score 0):

ValueError: Of the four parameters: **start**, **end**, **periods**, and **freq**, exactly three must be specified:

```py
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('20180101', periods=6)

pd.date_range(start='2020-03-20 00:00', end='2020-03-21 00:00', periods=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but it may worth it
You don't have to specify periods while you give start and end just give
pd.date_range(start='2020-03-20 00:00', end='2020-03-21 00:00') or pd.date_range(start='2020-03-20 00:00', end='2020-03-21 00:00',freq='1Min')